# R tm package and cyrillic text

Tags: r, encoding, text-mining, tm

I am trying to do some text mining with russian text using tm package and have some issues.

preprocessing speed heavily depends on encoding.

```
library(tm)
rus_txt<-paste(readLines('http://lib.ru/LITRA/PUSHKIN/dubrowskij.txt',encoding='cp1251'), collapse=' ')
object.size(rus_txt)
eng_txt<-paste(readLines('http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1112/pg1112.txt',encoding='UTF-8'), collapse=' ')
object.size(eng_txt)
# text sizes nearly identical
rus_txt_utf8<-iconv(rus_txt, to='UTF-8')
system.time(rus_txt_lower<-tolower(rus_txt_utf8))
#3.17         0.00         3.19 
system.time(rus_txt_lower<-tolower(eng_txt))
#0.03         0.00         0.03
system.time(rus_txt_lower<-tolower(rus_txt))
#0.07         0.00         0.08
```

40 times faster! and on large corporas difference was up to 500 times!

Lets try to tokenize some text (this function used in TermDocumentMatrix):

```
some_text<-"Несколько  лет  тому  назад  в  одном  из своих  поместий жил старинный
русской барин, Кирила Петрович Троекуров. Его богатство, знатный род и связи
давали ему большой вес в губерниях, где  находилось его имение.  Соседи рады
были угождать малейшим его прихотям; губернские чиновники трепетали  при его
имени;  Кирила  Петрович принимал знаки  подобострастия как надлежащую дань;
дом его  всегда был полон  гостями, готовыми тешить  его барскую праздность,
разделяя  шумные,  а  иногда  и  буйные  его  увеселения.  Никто  не  дерзал
отказываться от его приглашения, или в известные  дни не являться  с должным
почтением в село  Покровское."
scan_tokenizer(some_text)
#[1] "Несколько"  "лет"        "тому"       "назад"      "в"          "одном"      "из"         "своих"     
# [9] "поместий"   "жил"        "старинный"  "русской"    "барин,"     "Кирила"     "Петрович"   "Троекуров."
#[17] "Его"        "богатство," "знатный"    "род"        "и"          "св"
```

oops... Seems R core function scan() see russian lower case letter 'я' as EOF. I tried diffrent encodings but I haven't answer how to fix this.

Ok lets try to remove punctuation:

```
removePunctuation("жил старинный русской барин, Кирила Петрович Троекуров")
#"жил старинный русской барин Кирила Петрови Троекуров"
```

Hmm...where is letter 'ч'? Ok with UTF-8 encoding this works fine, but it took some time to found it.
 also I had issue with removeWords() function perfomance but can't reproduce it.
**Main question is: How to read and tokenize texts with letter 'я'?**
my locale:

```
Sys.getlocale()
#[1] "LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251"
```

Comment: One thing I found is use strsplit() function instead of scan()

Comment: Hahaha. I have same problem with 'я'. R is so ridiculous.

Comment: Just use text2vec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Question**: How to read and tokenize texts with letter 'я'? **Answer**: try to write your own tokenizer and use it. For example:

```
my_tokenizer <- function (x) 
{
  strsplit(iconv(x, to='UTF-8'), split='([[:space:]]|[[:punct:]])+', perl=F)[[1]]
}
 TDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus,control=list(tokenize=my_tokenizer, weighting=weightTf, wordLengths = c(3,10)))
```

**2)** Performance heavily depend on... performance of **tolower function**. May be this is a bug, I don't know, but on every time you call it you have to convert your text into native encoding using enc2native. (of course if your text language is not english).

```
doc.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(enc2native(textVector)))
```

And moreover after all text preprocessing on your corpus you have to convert it again. (this is because TermDocumentMatrix and many other function in **tm** package internally use **tolower**)

`tm_map(doc.corpus, enc2native)`

So your full flow will look like something like this:

```
createCorp <-function(textVector)
{
  doc.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(enc2native(textVector)))
  doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, tolower)
  doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, removePunctuation)
  doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, removeWords, stopwords("russian"))
  doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, stemDocument, "russian")
  doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, stripWhitespace)
  return(tm_map(doc.corpus, enc2native))
}
my_tokenizer <- function (x) 
{
  strsplit(iconv(x, to='UTF-8'), split='([[:space:]]|[[:punct:]])+', perl=F)[[1]]
}
TDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus,control=list(tokenize=my_tokenizer, weighting=weightTf, wordLengths = c(3,10)))
```